# facebook php sdk page token

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I have an application "Tipsters Corner" and a page ,also called Tipsters Corner.
I want to post on that page.I managed to do this using the token obtained from the graph explorer.
But I do not understand the difference between all the tokens.
I have a dropdown ,with the following options :
Graph Explorer
Tipsters Corner Application
I click Get Token.I get a token,a different one depending on what I selected in the dropdown.
I can post to my facebook application using any of the tokens.What is the difference between them.
Also,if I enter me/accounts I see my page/pages and another access token over there.What is that ?
Is that the token for the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tokens that you retrieve from the Graph Explorer are short duration [User Access Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) which are generated different for different applications and different permissions.

The Access tokens that you retrieve when navigating to `/me/accounts` end point are the [Page Access tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) for various Pages you administer or are associated with. These access tokens do expire, but if retrieved from the `/me/accounts` end point using long lived access token these do not expire ([documented here](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/#page_access_token)) and can impersonate things done by application as the Page itself.

You may further like to give the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) about access token a read.

Comment: Your answer partially answers my question.But you are not correct in one matter.The tokens for the pages do expire,after just 1 hour.

Comment: @AlinNiculescu, yes you are correct. This might have skipped from my mind. Sorry for that. i have updated my answer to be more specific