# Facebook post on page with php sdk 4.4

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know there are other similar post like this one, but most I think are not for my case and I am deffinitly missing something that breaks my process of developing this stuff.

So... I have a website where I post acticle news, I would like when I publish a new article to be posted on my facebook page automatically without redirecting me to login or etc... ( is it even possible ? )

So I have my facebook app, with it and token and what I do is

```
require __DIR__ . '/classes/facebook/autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id,$app_secret);

$session = FacebookSession::newAppSession();

$response = (new FacebookRequest(
      $session, 'POST', '/{PAGE_ID}/feed', array(
        'link' => 'www.example.com',
        'message' => 'User provided message'
      )
    ))->execute()->getGraphObject();
```

but no matter what I try i got permision errors, for auth and stuff like that.

I know I am doing something stupid, but because there are milion sdk's for facebook I can't find a correct example for my case.

Can someplease please help me with providing a working example where I just have to fill my app id, app sicret and page id in order for this to work ? 
And if I need to edit something on my page to set perissions etc.. also if possible to explain the way they need to be set.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an "Extended Page Access Token" for that. How to get specific Access Tokens is explained well in the following links:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Main principle:

- Authorize a User with `publish_actions` and `manage_pages` permissions
- Extend the User Access Token
- Use `/me/accounts` with that Extended User Token to get Extended Page Tokens for all your Pages

There are also several Stackoverflow threads about this already, for example: [facebook php sdk page token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16540231/facebook-php-sdk-page-token)

Comment: nope, I can't do it  "Report: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user." :( no matter what I try

Comment: well...not sure what you tried, but that error message means exactly what it says: you are not using an active access token. read the steps at "Main principle", and debug your access tokens in the debugger if they don´t work: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Answer (score 0):

"use Facebook\FacebookSession;" need PHP 5.3>